# jQuery submit form without reloading page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

I'm not very familiar with jQuery. I'm trying to make a form that is submitted in the background without reloading page.

I have a hidden div which shows and hides on click, inside the div there's a form.

I have two problems:

1) When the form validation fails, the form is still submitted. I tried to put validation and submission codes in condition `if(validation == valid) { $.ajax.... }` but it does not work properly.

2) After the form is submitted the div automatically hides, so successful message cannot be seen.

Here's the code:

```
$().ready(function() { 

    // Validate the form when it is submitted, using validation plugin.
    var validator = $("#contactform").validate({
        errorContainer: container,
        errorLabelContainer: $(),
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    onfocusout: false,
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) { 
error.insertBefore(element);    
}   
    });
});

$(function() {

    //This submits a form
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.php",
            data: $("#contactform").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }

        })
    })
})


//This shows and hides div onclick
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $(".slidingDiv").hide(); 
        $(".show_hide").show(); 
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){ 
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Rather than bind to the click event (`input[type=submit]`) you should bind to the *`submit`* event for the form.

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

I'm also not sure about the validation.  If it runs asynchronously, a callback is required.  If it runs synchronously, when does it get triggered?  It seems like it should be done when the form is submitted unless your validation plugin does that on its own:

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).validate(options)) {
        $.ajax
```

Using `e.preventDefault` will prevent reload and should allow your success div to display.

Comment: Thank you, e.preventDefault did the trick for submitting and success div.

Comment: i want to prevent refreshing after submitting the form..this code is not working properly

Comment: This worked for me locally. But when I uploaded to my hosted server, the .on("submit", ..) call was throwing an undefined error.. no idea why , because I would think I have the same version of jQuery wherever my code is deployed?!   I found an alternative to update the line to be like this: $("form").submit(function(e){..}); .. which then worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Please check which jQuery version you are using because in after jQuery 1.8.2 "success" function from jQuery Ajax is deprecated.

Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent actual submit event.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use `event.preventDefault();` to keep the form from submitting
-http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

2) There isn't anything in the given script that should be causing #result to hide, but you can try `$('#result').show()` and see if that brings it back

Comment: Seth, it's not the #result that hides it's a $(".slidingDiv")

Comment: Ok then toggle back on .sliddingDiv