# How to stay on same php after form submit but still save form entries in a file?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have a html form in which I want to save all the entries of all the fields into a file using php.

- If I am able to save entries successfully then I want to give popup message saying `{bytes} bytes written to file`.
- If I am not able to write successfully then I want to give popup message saying `There was an error writing this file`.
- And if the user doesn't have write access then it should give popup message - `Write access revoked`.

I call `save.php` file from the form action to save all the entries in a file and add do some sort of validations.

Below is my `index.php` file which has form in it -

```
<?php
 
declare(strict_types = 1);
 
session_start();
 
require_once 'helpers.php';
 
if (! check_auth()) {
    redirect('login.php');
    return;
}
 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Website Title</h1>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Welcome back, <?= $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>!</p>
    </div>
 
    <form action="save.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="field1" />
        <input type="text" name="field2" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
    </form>
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is my `save.php` file -

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

session_start();

require_once 'helpers.php';

if (!check_auth())
{
    redirect('login.php');
    return;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    if (!isWriteAccess())
    {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Write access revoked', ]);
        return;
    }

    // Your code here...
    if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']))
    {
        $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\r\n";
        $ret = file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data,  LOCK_EX);
        if ($ret === false)
        {
            die('There was an error writing this file');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$ret bytes written to file";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die('no post data to process');
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement**

As of now whenever I click save button on my form which is in `index.php`, it just prints everything on my browser as the response and also redirects to `save.php` but I don't want that. I want to show all messages on popup window but it should stay on same `index.php` file.

- If I am able to write successfully to the file, then I should see `some bytes written to the file` as a popup but it should stay on `index.php` file only.
- If there is a write access issue then it should show `Write access revoked` as a popup but it should stay on `index.php` file only.

How can I make sure that whenever I click save button on my form which is in index.php it should stay on the same page but still do all sorts of validations and save entries in a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have jquery connected, so use $.ajax() to submit the form like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233254/jquery-submit-form-without-reloading-page) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form). In the 'success:' handler the `data` variable will contain responce from your `save.php`:

```
  success: function(data) {
     $('#result').html(data);
     }
```

therefore you can pop up a window with this results. Something like that in your index.php:

```
<script>
$(function() {

    //This submits a form
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    var method = form.attr('method');
    
    $.ajax({
           type: method, // "POST"
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data) {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
    
});
</script>
```

PS: You can easily get answer to your question by [yourself](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=jquery%20submit%20form%20without%20reloading%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=jquery%20submit%20form%20without%20reloading%20site%3Astackoverflow.com), such questions was answered here a lot. All trick is to add `site:stackoverflow.com` to your request in Google.

Comment: Thanks granty. Yeah I noticed SO has bunch of solutions for that but I wasn't sure on how to integrate them. I saw your example but still couldn't figure out how to integrate it with my example. Can you provide an example on how this will work with my solution? If I understand correctly I should add ajax code in my index.php?

Comment: Yes, add script code into index.php. I have edited my answer to include example you requested. This is exact code from second link I gave you :)